# Linked List Iterator adds too many numbers

Tags: java, listiterator

I wrote a program for my Java class and I can't seem to figure out what it is doing wrong. I populate a LinkedList with 25 random integers between 1 and 100. I then sort the list and output the sum and average. Then I remove the odd numbers and output the sum and average of the new list. However, when I do the final calculations it also seems to add the largest number from the original list as well. If the largest number from the first list is even it adds it twice.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.*;


public class randomNumberCollection
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count = 0;

    //Create LinkedList object
    LinkedList<Integer> numList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    Integer nextNum = null;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 25; counter ++)
    {
        nextNum = new Integer((int)(Math.random() * 100));
        numList.add(nextNum);
    }
    //output random number LinkedList unsorted
    System.out.printf("Unsorted -- \n" + "Here are the numbers: \n" + numList);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    //Sort LinkedList
    Collections.sort(numList);
    System.out.printf("Sorted -- \n" + "Here are the numbers: \n" + numList);
    System.out.println();

    //Output sorted list sum and average
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = numList.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
        count += ((Integer) iterator.next()).intValue();

    System.out.printf("The sum of the numbers is %d and the average is %.2f ", count, (double) count / numList.size());
    System.out.println();

    ListIterator <Integer> iterator2 = numList.listIterator();
    int listElement = 0;

    while(iterator2.hasNext())
    {
        listElement = (Integer)iterator2.next();
        if (listElement %2 == 1)
        {
            iterator2.remove();
        }
    }

    ListIterator<Integer> iterator3 = numList.listIterator();
    while (iterator3.hasNext())
        listElement += ((Integer) iterator3.next()).intValue();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("With the odd numbers removed -- \n" + "Here are the numbers: \n" + numList);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The sum of the numbers is %d and the average is %.2f ", listElement, (double) listElement / numList.size());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

After iterating through the (sorted) list to remove the odd numbers, `listElement` holds the value of the last element of the (sorted) list.

You need to reset `listElement` to zero before the final iteration through the list.

It would be a good idea to have a separate method that iterates through a list, and returns the sum of the integers in the list. This would reduce code duplication.

You also don't need all the casts to `Integer`. Because `ListIterator` is a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), the compiler knows that the iterators' `next` methods return `Integer`s.